# open a popup in a UIWebView and retrieve a value to the opener

Tags: ios, uiwebview, popup, uiwebviewdelegate, window.opener

I'm developing an iPad app to load a web page (an ERP) and work with it. The problem here is that I can't modify the web page code (big site... 1000 pages or more) but we use all over the site search components that opens new windows where you select a value and it is returned to the opener window.

Opening a new uiwebview is not the issue here, the problem is that the webview delegate is not even called when the user selects a value so i can't figure out a way to retrieve it.

I already tried several ways... I tried to overwrite the javascript window.open to load the new page in a frame but i couldn't make it work either.

Somebody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've found these links that seems to answer to your problem :

http://geneindex.keithching.com/2009/07/12/how-to-open-javascript-popup-windows-in-uiwebview/

http://niw.at/articles/2009/02/06/how-to-enable-the-popup-window-on-uiwebview/en

Basically it explains how to convert "open in new window" type links to some clickable links in an uiwebview !